# Why does creating large amounts of SKNodes take so long

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a random item spinner for my iOS App in Swift using SpriteKit, but currently my method is not very efficient, and I am almost certain it cannot be the best way of achieving what I am aiming for.  The process I am currently following is essentially.
- On scene load, loop through a list of 13 different items (stored in JSON)
- Create a group of nodes showing the relevant data
- Add each group of nodes to a second group of nodes, moving each one along the x axis slightly, creating a long line of SKNode's (the items for the spinner)
- Moving that group along the x-axis, to give the impression of it spinning through the items

But this method takes about 6 seconds to even load the scene (and delay is on adding the nodes to the much larger node: `group.addChild(spinnerItem)` and as I am only new to Swift I am sure there is a better way of me doing this, so any help/advice appreciate to improve this code cause it's in serious need of efficiency improvements!

Here is the didMove function...

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    var xPos = CGFloat(self.frame.width + 150)
    var eventWeapon = weapon()

    for n in 0...13{
        eventWeapon = getWeapon(caseName: "chromaCase", weaponID: n)
        print(eventWeapon)
        let texture = createSpinnerItem(wName: "\(eventWeapon.name)", wSkin: "\(eventWeapon.skin)", wColor: "\(eventWeapon.color)")
        let spinnerItem = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
        spinnerItem.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        group.addChild(spinnerItem)

        xPos = xPos + 300 * 1.2
    }

    self.addChild(group)
    group.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -5000, y: 0, duration: 2))
}
```

and the `createSpinnerItem` function used within that...

```
func createSpinnerItem(wName: String, wSkin: String, wColor: String) -> SKTexture {
    let object = SKNode()

    let bGround = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
    bGround.fillColor = color.offWhite
    bGround.strokeColor = color.gray
    bGround.lineWidth = 5
    object.addChild(bGround)

    let titleBG = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 300, height: 100))
    if wColor == "blue"{ titleBG.fillColor = color.CSGOblue }
    if wColor == "red"{ titleBG.fillColor = color.CSGOred }
    if wColor == "pink"{ titleBG.fillColor = color.CSGOpink }
    if wColor == "purple"{ titleBG.fillColor = color.CSGOpurple }
    titleBG.strokeColor = color.gray
    titleBG.lineWidth = 5
    titleBG.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -150 + 50)
    object.addChild(titleBG)

    let weaponName = SKLabelNode()
    weaponName.text = wName
    weaponName.fontColor = color.white
    weaponName.fontSize = 40
    weaponName.fontName = "Avenir-Regular"
    weaponName.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    weaponName.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -150 + 70)
    object.addChild(weaponName)

    let weaponSkin = SKLabelNode()
    weaponSkin.text = wSkin
    weaponSkin.fontColor = color.white
    weaponSkin.fontSize = 20
    weaponSkin.fontName = "Avenir-Regular"
    weaponSkin.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    weaponSkin.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -150 + 30)
    object.addChild(weaponSkin)

    return object
}
```

Comment: Questions - Why do people always put tags in their titles?

Comment: hmm?  I believe I have put my tags within the relevant `Tags` section of the post

Comment: You added "Swift" to the title. There is no need, it is already indicated in the tags that you are using Swift.

Comment: @LuckyBowers: So only the `didMove` takes 6 seconds? Or are you considering the whole startup process. On which device are you testing it?

Comment: @appzYourLife Well it all runs pretty smoothly, but when adding the nodes to the `group` parent node, it delays a fair bit each iteration.  I am testing on an iPhone6

Comment: Wait,  how does this even work,  You are returning an `SKNode` when you want an `SKTexture`

Comment: Oh sorry there is a slight mis-match in that code just noticed @Knight0fDragon!  One other method I tried was converting all the nodes to textures, but that worked even slower

Comment: well anyway,  to find your lag,the first line of the for loop, do `let date = Date()` and just put a `print("Time: \(-date.timeIntervalSinceNow)")` to find out what is sucking up all your time

Comment: @LuckyBowers So what actually createSpinnerItem method returns? You have to update your question with what can produce what you are saying

Comment: Also using SKShapeNodes and SKLabelNodes like this is a not the way to go really. Just do the math ( 2xSKShapeNodes + 2xSKLabelNodes ) x 14 = 56 draw calls to render a scene. Means your app will become slow (if it isn't already) very shortly if you contiue doing things like this ;) Use SKSpriteNodes where possible. Those can be rendered in batches.

Comment: How do SKSpriteNodes get better batching? I have a scene that's generating 3000 to 10,000 SKSpriteNodes, all copies of the same content, and they never get batched. My node count is always 3000 to 10,000. Things slow down past about 7000

Comment: @Confused If sprites coming from the same atlas and don't have different blend mode, then batch rendering will work. By the way, number of nodes shown in the debugging area has nothing with batch rendering. Number of draw calls is affected when batch rendering working / not working. You can enable this in your game view controller by doing `view.showsDrawCount = true` SpriteKit is capable to render many nodes as long as number of draw counts are kept to low.

Comment: Cheers! I am not using any textures, these are just "particles" made up of boxes; SKSpriteNodes with some colour. I'll check this out. Never thought to check for a draw count feature stat. I'm a moron! :: UPDATE :: It's BATCHING, and that's BITCH'N!

Comment: @Confused If nodes are just colored, then they should be drawn in single draw call. But batching process can be interrupted like from the example above (blendMode) and for example if a SKSpriteNode has a child(ren) on its own which can't be drawn in batches. And those are,SKShapeNode, SKLabelNode and some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the first things you want to do is to determine if your "perceived" delay is real or not versus just the overhead of the app being launched. 6 sec is a long period of time, so without measurements, one doesn't know if you're just exaggerating or understanding the true delay. I will get into what I mean by perceived in a few. You should do as KnightOfDragon suggests and actually measure the time.

I do see one issue with the code right now, and it is not uncommon for what I see with people's code using SK on SO. And this goes into the perceived notion mentioned above. The actual CPU usage required to process your work may not be large, however what you experience during run time may not match that actual expected CPU loading. Why? You are probably doing a lot of work on the main thread. From loading the JSON to potentially creating the textures. As such, you will find that by starving the main thread, you can see slow downs you would not otherwise see. The generalized problem, app or game, is that I see many people try and literally load everything in their `didMove` or if an app `viewDidLoad`. What you really want to do is treat that more like a bootstrapping start point. Do the minimal amount of work there to setup, and then asynchronously dispatch the time consuming stuff using your favorite method. This will alleviate you locking up the main thread while you do stuff like file I/O.

Yes, this does complicate your code a bit to be able to handle this, but this is approach is not atypical. Most engines have loading systems to help load items in the background and notify when they are done. While the loading occurs you usually see a loading screen or some other indicator.

Just keep in mind that when you modify the `SKNode` hierarchy you'll need to make sure you do it on the right thread (for example when you `addChild` to the active scene). You can do it either via an `SKAction` or on the main thread. Your app can crash otherwise.

Comment: Thanks so much for all that!  I will run the tests you suggested, one other thing however, if I was to generate the textures outside of my `GameView.swift` file, the line `let myTexture = view?.texture(from: object)` errors as there is no view in just a blank swift file.  So how can i create a texture from an SKNode?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You need to load your own textures via whatever means you want. https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sktexture